# Added 2nd css dropdown and it won't line up

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have added a second CSS dropdown menu on my page and it appears on the left of the page. The first one has text center-aligned and everything works great. I added a second one for when an admin is logged in for admin operations.
The text is right-aligned in this menu and the dropdown appears on the left of the screen.

Here is a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/q0nsrdgo/

Html

```
<div id="loginbar">
<ul>
<li>Welcome Xenarious | </li><li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>&nbsp;|</li>    
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Admin Controls</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="addcustomer.php">Add Customer</a>
            <a href="updatecustomer.php">Edit Customer</a>
            <a href="addproduct.php">Add Product</a>
            <a href="updateproduct.php">Update Product</a>
        </div>
         |</li>    <li><a href="orders.php">Orders</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<header>
    <img src="../common/techtitan-title.png">
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="products.html" 
 class="dropbtn">Products</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <!--<a href="products.html">Desktops</a>-->
            <a href="products.html">Notebooks</a>
            <a href="products.html">Tablets</a>
            <a href="products.html">Smartphones</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
```

Css

```
#loginbar {
text-align: right;
background-color: #1D6000;
color: #FFD700;
font-size: 10pt;
z-index: 2;
overflow: auto;
width: 100%;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
header {
background-color: #1D6000;
margin-bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
z-index: 1;
}
header img {
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
}

nav {
overflow: auto;
width: 100%;
display: block;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #1D6000;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(5,5,5,0.5);
border-bottom: 3px ridge #FFD700;
font-size: 14pt;
}
nav ul, #loginbar ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #1D6000;
}
nav li, #loginbar li {
/*float: left*/
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: #FFD700;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #FFD700;
color: #1D6000;
}
li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #1D6000;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(5,5,5,0.5);
/*z-index: 1;*/    
}
.dropdown-content a {
color: #FFD700;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #FFD700;
color: #1D6000;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS as follows -

```
nav li, #loginbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Since only your `.dropdown` class was set to `inline-block`, the dropdown wasn't being displayed as required.

Comment: Ya I used `right: 0;` to make it clickable. I just don't understand why when Its the same code as my nav which works fine it won't display correctly.

Comment: Updated answer to fix issue. Please check.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.